# Error Installing Windows 10 development tools for Visual Studio 2015 RC on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, win-universal-app, visual-studio-2015

I am running Windows 8.1 and I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise RC with Blend.

I am trying to install the Windows 10 development tools for Visual Studio 2015 RC and getting the following error:

> ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Windows 10 SDK 10.0.10069 : The installer failed. User cancelled installation. Error code: -2147023294

Has anyone else gotten this error and found a solution to successfully install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through a quick google of the error code you provided, I found an article with the following post:

> To get unblocked, go to https://dev.windows.com/downloads/windows-10-developer-tools. Scroll to the bottom of the page and install the Windows 10 SDK and Windows 10 emulators outside of Visual Studio setup.

Source:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17bc9d5e-2ea7-4149-bb75-23997db8bd25/known-issue-emulators-for-windows-mobile-10010069-the-installer-failed-user-cancelled?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues

I cannot speak for the solutions' effectiveness personally, but it was a marked answer. I hope this helps!

Comment: I can confirm that it worked for me!  Just installed the Standalone Windows SDK for Windows 10 and the Microsoft Emulator for Windows 10 Mobile, then ran the installer again for the Windows 10 development tools for Visual Studio 2015 RC.

Comment: One thing to note, though.  There are several interesting templates under Visual C# > Windows > Windows Universal.  But under JavaScript > Windows > Windows Universal there is still only the Blank App template and the "Download Windows Universal Tools" template that originally took me to the download page for the Windows 10 development tools for Visual Studio 2015 RC.

Answer (score 1):

We've fixed this issue, and have released an update as of 7PM PDT 30 April 2015.

New installs of Visual Studio 2015 RC should expect to no longer encounter this problem, unless you lose your internet connection during installation. (That is, this error now indicates that the Windows SDK or Windows Emulator setup invoked by Visual Studio setup has lost internet connectivity and cannot download necessary files.)

- To fix the issue, re-run setup and select the features "Universal
  Windows App Development Tools" and/or "Emulators for Windows Mobile"
  again.

If you have already installed Visual Studio and encountered this problem, you can now modify your Visual Studio installation to successfully install.
Go to Program & Features, select Visual Studio 2015 RC, and select Change.

- Click Modify, then select the features "Universal Windows App
  Development Tools" and/or "Emulators for Windows Mobile", and click
  Update.
- Note that "Universal Windows App Development Tools" will be already selected. This is expected. Keep it selected, and click Update.

An alternate solution is to install the Windows 10 SDK and Windows Emulators separately. Go to https://dev.windows.com/downloads/windows-10-developer-tools. Scroll to the bottom of the page and install the Windows 10 SDK and Windows 10 emulators outside of Visual Studio setup.

(See also this known issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17bc9d5e-2ea7-4149-bb75-23997db8bd25/)

Thanks!
-Paul Chapman (program manager with Visual Studio at Microsoft)

Comment: Hi Paul,The VS installation did not complete due to a  spotty internet connection. So I installed the Windows 10 SDK and Windows 10 emulators outside of Visual Studio as you suggested. However VS 2015 still does not recognise this and does not open Win 10 projects or lets me create a new one.
I did do a repair of VS 2015 installation and it detected Windows 10 sdk exists in the logs as well but no entry in the new project dialog.

Comment: Yeah... Im installing this on 16 machines at work.  Actually I'm NOT.  I'm getting errors on every single machine.  -2147023294.  Its not a connectivity issue.  Its more of a software doesn't work as expected issue.

Answer (score 0):

Installed Windows 10 installed from scratch.
Installed VS2015 from ISO.

VS2015 failed to install the Windows 10 emulators.

No loss of connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 cents. 
 I tried all the methods in all the forums and the tools failed to install for me on Windows 10. Then as a last resort, I enabled 'Developer Mode' in Settings and tried installing the tools again and voila! They did.