# VS2015 unable to install universal windows app tools

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Professional, and I would like to use Windows 10 SDK for mobile development. I checked everything at the installation panel, and it seems, that everything is installed successfully. However, in VS there are no templates available.

[image]

After I clicked OK, the installation starts again, which finishes withtout errors, however the process is very fast, so it couldn't install 3GB at that time. After that in VS the templates still missing. I reinstall visual studio wihtout any success.

In the programs and features I can see the SDK and the emulators.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok guys, never mind, after 10th uninstall-install finally works.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.

I've also tried installing the SDK offline from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads) like suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977779/error-installing-windows-10-development-tools-for-visual-studio-2015-rc-on-windo) thread. Still no go.
I'm on my second reinstall/install of VS and I don't remember how many times I've installed/modified the missing components in VS.